# scipy -- how to extract randomly an array from a list

Tags: python, random, scipy

i have these:

```
    a=sc.array([0,1])
    b=sc.array([1,0])
    c=sc.array([0,-1])
    d=sc.array([-1,0])
    orientation_list=(sc.array([a,b,c,d])).tolist()
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------

    #i am trying sth like this
    tab=sc.random.random_integers(orientation_list)
```

I want the 'tab' to retrieve randomly one of the above arrays.For example 'tab=[0,1]'
Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import random
>>> tab = random.choice([[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, -1], [-1, 0]])
>>> tab
[-1, 0]
```

Your code creates a bunch of NumPy arrays, then a list of these NumPy arrays, then transforms this list itself into a NumPy array and finally transforms everything back to a list.  The code above skips all those (rather pointless) conversions and uses Python's built-in `random` module instead of NumPy's `numpy.random`.